# How automatically generate coupon code from $100?

Tags: php, magento2

I need add coupon code from $100 to newsletter. I did rewrite \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber in the method sendConfirmationSuccessEmail

```
->setTemplateVars(
['subscriber'   => $this, 
 'coupon_code' => $this->getCouponCode()
])
```

`protected function getCouponCode() {
        . . . 
        . . .
        return $couponCode;
}`

How automatically generate coupon code in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a Shopping Cart Price Rule? If not, that's where to start. In the admin area, go to Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules > Add New Rule, and define a Specific Coupon with Use Auto Generation selected.

Once you have defined the rule for whatever specific discount you wish to offer, save the rule and make a note of the rule ID from the the Shopping Cart Price Rules row showing the rule you just created.

Then add something like the following, using the rule ID of the rule you just created:

The function below takes an associative array with the following options:

rule_id = the rule ID, from above

qty = number of coupon codes to instruct Magento to generate

length = length of each generated coupon code

format = alphanum (for alphanumeric codes) OR alpha (for alphabetical codes) OR num (for numeric codes)

```
protected function getCouponCode($couponData)
{
    $rule = $this->_loadSalesRule($ruleId);
    // Reference the MassGenerator on this rule.
    /** @var Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon_Massgenerator $generator */
    $generator = $rule->getCouponMassGenerator();
    // Validate the generator
    if (!$generator->validateData($couponData)) {
        $this->_critical(Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Coupon AutoGen API: Invalid parameters passed in.'),
            Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        // Set the data for the generator
        $generator->setData($couponData);
        // Generate a pool of coupon codes for the Generate Coupons rule
        $generator->generatePool();
    }
}
```